# How to replace text in a string with values from a column in sql

Tags: sql, string, replace

```
Exp                                 Major       Start
__________________________________________________________
                                   |        |
'My names are W.Major and W.Start' |  Hal   |      Bark
___________________________________|________|_________________
'W.Major is a doctor'              |  Mark  |      Slope
___________________________________|________|_______________
```

Hi All suppose I have the table above in SQL server management studio
and for any text in the Exp column I want to replace W.Major with the value in the Major column and wherever there is a W.Start I want to replace it with the value in the Start column.

Do you know what type of SP I have to write to get this accomplished?

Comment: A SQL Server Stored procedure...

Comment: What have you tried so far. Is this homework? And if it is, we are not going to be able to do this work for you when you get into the real world. Have a try and ask for specific help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use a Dynamic SQL and UNPIVOT to get table with all unit replacements and then you run a while loop to replace expressions one by one till you get your result.

I am sure there can be better techniques but here is my solution.
Please mark it as answer for my effort :)

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb.dbo.#temptable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temptable
CREATE TABLE #tempTable  (  ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),  [Exp] nvarchar(4000) not NULL,  replacementWord nvarchar(50) not null, Wordvalue nvarchar(50) not null, flag  bit null, ReplacedExp nvarchar(4000) null)
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @queryRWords VARCHAR(2000)
SELECT @queryRWords =
        STUFF((select DISTINCT '],['+ LTRIM(C.name) from sys.Columns  C INNER JOIN  sys.objects O on O.object_id=C.object_id where  O.name='yourtable' and O.type_desc='USER_TABLE' and C.name not like 'Exp' ORDER BY '],['+LTRIM(C.name) FOR XML PATH('') ),1,2,'') + ']'
SET @query='INSERT INTO #tempTable(Exp, replacementWord, WordValue) select [Exp], [replacementWord],[WordValue] FROM (SELECT [Exp], [major],[start] FROM [yourtable]) p
UNPIVOT([Wordvalue] FOR [replacementWord] IN ('+@queryRWords+'))AS unpvt'
EXECUTE(@query)
UPDATE #tempTable SET ReplacedExp=[Exp]
DECLARE @ExpCount INT
SELECT @ExpCount=  COUNT(*) FROM #tempTable
WHILE @ExpCount >0
BEGIN

    IF((SELECT [Exp] From #tempTable where Id=@ExpCount)<>(SELECT [Exp] from #tempTable where Id=(@ExpCount-1)))
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE #tempTable   SET FLAG=1, ReplacedExp=  REPLACE(ReplacedExp, CAST('W.'+replacementWord AS VARCHAR), WordValue) FROM    #tempTable WHERE Id=@ExpCount
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            UPDATE #tempTable SET ReplacedExp=  REPLACE(ReplacedExp, CAST('W.'+replacementWord AS VARCHAR), WordValue) FROM    #tempTable WHERE Id=@ExpCount
            UPDATE #tempTable SET  ReplacedExp= (SELECT ReplacedExp FROM #temptable where Id=@ExpCount) WHERE Id=(@ExpCount-1)
        END
SET @ExpCount=@ExpCount-1
END
UPDATE #tempTable
SET flag=1 where Id=1

SELECT ReplacedExp FROM #tempTable where flag=1
```

Comment: This was based on this table SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[yourtable](
 [Exp] [nvarchar](3000) NULL,
 [Major] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Start] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

Comment: Hi Dhruv, trid to upvote this, but it wouldnt let me!

Comment: @user3171919 Thanks for marking my reply as answer. Hope the query worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the sample TSQL where you can have a good start**

```
SELECT  Exp, Major, Start
        , Replace(Replace(Exp, 'W.Major', Major), 'W.Start', Start) As Result
FROM    [Your Table Name]
```

Comment: Hi Jade suppose I had 50 columns. like W.Major, W.Start,W.A, W.B,...and so on. Is there a method that would not involve hardcoding ?

Comment: If you are trying to do it in a single statement, unfortunately I have no idea and perhaps may be not possible.  May be make those 50 columns  into rows, then do it an application or T-SQL that utilizes cursor.